# if radio has an id addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what i want to build is if is check first radio to rotate the value 90deg if is checked middle one to rotate 180deg,how can i do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
        var result = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
        if (result.length > 0) {
            $("#final2").html(result.val() + "is checked");
        } else {
            $("#final2").html("No radio button cheked");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="v1" value="1">Option 1</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="v2" value="31">Option 2</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="v3" value="33">Option 3</label>
<button type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="final2">
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to rotate?

Comment: So what problem you are facing? BTW one `});` is missing in your script code

Comment: what do you want to rotate

Comment: i am trying when is checked first one to print value and what i want is to be rotate at 90deg first next one if is checked the value printed in that div to be rotate at 180deg.

Comment: you mean you want to see which radio button is checked then rotate something?

Comment: What does rotating 90 and 180 degrees have to do with `addclass`?

Comment: @EzraMancini That's exactly what you wrote in the question. We didn't understand it there, saying it again doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry if you don`t understand me but what i want is when first option is checked and submit value to be printed and rotate text at 90deg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement:

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
    var result = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
    if (result.length > 0) {
        $("#final2").html(result.val() + "is checked");
        switch(result.val()) {
            case 1:
                // rotate 90 degrees
                $("#result").removeClass("rotate180").addClass("rotate90");
                break;
            case 31:
                // Rotate 180 degrees
                $("#result").removeClass("rotate90").addClass("rotate180");
                break;
            case 33:
                // do something else
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $("#final2").html("No radio button cheked");
    }
});
```

Comment: So in case 1 i need to add $("#final2").addClass("rotate90"); ?

Comment: If that's how you rotate the DIV, then that's what you need to do.

Comment: I want to rotate only the value (text) not entire div.Thank you!

Comment: That's a CSS issue, it has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: how i can add a class to that div because what i put above is not working ,please enlighten me senpai :D

Comment: You probably also need to remove other classes like `rotate180`.

Comment: Ok,i know my english is very bad but look what i wanted to do here is an example what i am trying to do.  https://jsfiddle.net/gz27Lp97/1/

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the correction. See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/gz27Lp97/3/